# unity app apk "problem parsing package" on android 11

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have built a mobile game on the Unity game engine, version  2021.3.0f1 . I am now trying to build the game to test it on my phone. As per google play's API level policies, all apps must target api level 31 or above.

However, building my app with api level 31 renders it unusable on my phone. The APK throws a "problem parsing the package" error when trying to install.

If I switch back to API level 30, I can install the APK on my phone.

My phone runs android 11.

My latest build is API level 32 and it is experiencing the same issue. The problem with API level 32 is that certain phones with android 12 start having the "problem parsing the package" error. Android 13 and Android 12L work okay.

I'd be grateful for a solution since I have been unable to find any on my own.

Comment: There is a possible solution for this. In the androidmanifest.xml file, set the value android:exported="true" and try building again. I hope it helps. Take care.

Comment: already done. I have added the android:exported ="true" attribute corresponding to the intent-filter tags. This doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

My minimum apk level was the same as my max apk level. It was a mistake on my part.

If you have this issue, check your min apk level and set it equal to or below the android version you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using plugins for android, then make sure that you have entered all the necessary data. I get this error when I forgot to enter the game services ID for Essential Kit.